# Will I meet trouble when I apply Dispatchers.IO both Flow and CoroutineScope?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

In order to avoid hard work in main thread, I apply `.flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)` for a Flow `listIncompleted` in `class TranslateIncompleted`.

You know, sometimes when other users invoke the suspend function, he invoke it within  `CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO) .launch {...}` .

1:  Will I meet trouble when I apply `Dispatchers.IO` both `Flow` and `CoroutineScope` ?

2:  Which way is better between using  `Flow.flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)`  and using  `CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO)`  if I can use only one ?

```
class ServiceTranslate: Service() {

    @Inject lateinit var translateIncompleted: ITranslateIncompleted
    private var job: Job? = null

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        job = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO) .launch {
            translateIncompleted.translateIncompletedAndUpdate()
        }
    }
  
    override fun onDestroy() {
       super.onDestroy()
       job?.cancel()
    }
    ...
}


class TranslateIncompleted @Inject constructor(
   ...
): ITranslateIncompleted {

    override suspend fun translateIncompletedAndUpdate() {

        val listIncompleted = handleMInfo.listIncompleted()        
        listIncompleted
            .flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)
            .collect {
               ...
            }
    }
}
```

**Added Content:**

To Tenfour04: Thanks!

A:   I have made some modifications to my code. Does it look good now?

B:  I don't believe that `onEach` is a block function, but `collect` is. I want collect to keep running and handling data as the flow changes. Since `onEach` only runs once, I don't think it's suitable for this particular case, right?

C:  Why is it a poor design to specify `Dispatchers.IO` on a Flow? If I specify Dispatchers.IO on a Flow, no matter what method to invoke the flow , I can  guarantee that the hard work runing in `Dispatchers.IO` thread.

Comment: Don't use `CoroutineScope()` unless you're really sure what you're doing. Usually, the scope should either be provided by your framework, or if all else fails you can use `runBlocking`.

Comment: Thanks! How can I invoke the suspend function in Service() if I don't use CoroutineScope()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `CoroutineScope(…).launch` is a code smell, because you should not be creating a new coroutine scope if you aren’t going to assign it to a property so you can cancel it at an appropriate time. (You could be assigning the returned Job to a property that you cancel at the appropriate time, but then you may as well have used GlobalScope.)

If you use LifecycleService instead of Service as your superclass, then you can use `lifecycleScope` to launch coroutines. But if you don’t, you should create a CoroutineScope with a SupervisorJob and cancel it in `onDestroy()`.

If you are launching a coroutine that must not be cancelled no matter what screen or service your app is in or not, then you can use GlobalScope, but you must be careful that you don’t capture references to things that could be memory leaks.

It is rare to need to specify Dispatchers.IO on a Flow that you got from somewhere else. It would be very poor design and against convention if some other class is publicly sharing a Flow that blocks. None of the Android, Google or Square libraries do that anywhere to my knowledge. The only place you should be using `flowOn` is after your own *blocking* code *added* to a Flow in a Flow operator, like in an `onEach` block.

Usually, if all I am doing in a coroutine is collecting a Flow, then I don’t use `launch` at all. You can use `onEach` and `launchIn` on the flow for cleaner syntax.

---

Edit:

A) Looks ok now because you make sure the Job is cancelled in `onDestroy`. You could make it a little more mistake-proof by using a `val` CoroutineScope property instead of a `var` Job? property. But it is unnecessary to specify a dispatcher since the only thing your coroutine does is call a suspend function.

B) I don’t know exactly what you’re trying to say. `onEach` is an operator. It doesn’t block or suspend, but the lambda you pass it to does suspend, and is called repeatedly for every upstream emission, just like the lambda passed to `collect` is called repeatedly for every upstream emission. You must not call blocking code in `onEach` unless you follow it with `flowOn`. `collect` doesn’t block either. It suspends.

I think maybe you don't have a clear understanding of exactly what the difference is between the three categories of synchronous function: a blocking function, a suspending function, and a function that does neither. All the Flow operators (including intermediate ones like `onEach`/`map` and terminal ones like `collect`/`first()`/`launchIn`/`stateIn`) are non-blocking and non-suspending, but the lambdas that you pass to them *are* suspending. They should not have blocking code inside the lambdas unless you ensure they are called on an appropriate dispatcher that can handle blocking code. `flowOn` changes the context of code in previous (higher up) operators, but cannot affect the downstream operator, including `collect`.

C) That’s not what I said. I said you should be able to assume a flow retrieved from another class doesn’t block, because if it does, the designer of that other class is setting a trap for you that breaks convention. If you are the designer of a class that creates a flow to pass to other classes, then you know where your blocking code is and which dispatcher is appropriate so you can fix it with `flowOn` internally before it is shared with other classes.

Which would you rather have?

Code A in an API:

```
/** Do anything you want with this flow. It is safe. */
fun retrieveAFlow() : Flow<Something> ...
```

Code B in an API:

```
/** Be very careful with this flow. It breaks convention and will block 
  a thread if you don't use a dispatcher that is safe for consuming IO 
  blocking work, so you have to collect it in a context that uses such a 
  dispatcher. Don't use Dispatchers.Default, though because this is IO 
  blocking work, not CPU blocking work! Hopefully you noticed this 
  documentation and read it very carefully and don't make a mistake 
  following these directions, or your app will not behave correctly! */
fun retrieveAFlow() : Flow<Something> ...
```